# need google tts workaround

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate, speech

So I put Google TTS on my website (http://jieshangxiaochi.blogspot.com/2015/04/guge-putonghua-yanjiang.html).

Three problems:
1. Google TTS only accepts 100 char max. How do I increase this?
2. Chinese speech rate is too fast. How do I reduce the speed?
3. When a link to a particular TTS is opened, clicking 'play' won't do, one must click 'Refresh' first. Why is that? (link example: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=%E6%8C%96%E9%BC%BB%E5%AD%94%20%E7%9A%84-%20%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E3%80%82%E5%94%89%EF%BC%8C%E5%A7%90%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E8%BF%99%E4%B9%88%E5%80%92%E9%9C%89%EF%BC%81%E5%81%8F%E5%81%8F%E5%B0%B1%E5%9C%A8%E6%88%91%E6%8C%96%E9%BC%BB%E5%AD%94%E6%8C%96%E5%BE%97%E5%85%A5%E8%BF%B7%E7%9A%84%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99%EF%BC%8C%E8%84%9A%E6%AD%A5%E5%A3%B0%E4%BC%A0%E6%9D%A5%EF%BC%8C%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E7%94%B7%E7%A5%9E%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7%E7%9A%84%E7%94%B7%E5%AD%90%E7%9C%8B%E5%88%B0%E4%BA%86%E6%88%91%E6%8C%96%E9%BC%BB%E5%AD%94%EF%BC%8C%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E6%88%91%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E5%81%9C%E6%AD%A2%E3%80%82%E5%A4%AA%E5%B0%B4%E5%B0%AC%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%8C%E5%93%8E%E5%91%80%EF%BC%8C%E5%B0%B4%E5%B0%AC%E6%AD%BB%E4%BA%86%E3%80%82)

What I have tried: Google around. 
On problem #1: They said Google translate speech now has no character limit, but why mine is still limited to 100?
On problem #2: Adding a dot between every Chinese characters. This slowed down the speed rate, but it became hard to differentiate one sentences from another. Giving two dots created the same delay as one dot.
On problem #3: I am at loss here.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?